# error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: regex, boost

I am trying to compile my C++ code using the GNU compiler under Linux using the following Makefile

```
CXX=gcc  #icpc
RM=rm -f
CPPFLAGS=-g -O3 -fopenmp
CFLAGS= -Wall -c
OPENMP   = -fopenmp
BIN = theVeecode_$(CXX)

LIBS= -L /path-to-boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_regex

CPPSRCS=mathtools.cpp time_.cpp read_input.cpp vee_ao_calc.cpp vee_mo_calc.cpp write_int2e.cpp memory_check.cpp
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(CPPSRCS))
OBJS+=$(COBJS)

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) main.cpp $(OPENMP) -o $(BIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BIN)

dist-clean: clean
        $(RM) $(BIN)
```

When I run the make command, I get the following error messages:

```
gcc    -g -O3 -fopenmp   -c -o read_input.o read_input.cpp
read_input.cpp:9:27: error: boost/regex.hpp: No such file or directory
read_input.cpp: In function 'void input::read_n_occ()':
read_input.cpp:95: error: 'boost' has not been declared
read_input.cpp:95: error: 'regex_search' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [read_input.o] Error 1
```

The read_input.cpp file starts with

```
#... // other includes
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

namespace xxx
{
 //some code here  
}
```

The library path "/path-to-boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/" contains the files
libboost_regex.a, libboost_regex.so and libboost_regex.so.1.53.0.

I don't understand why the compiler doesn't find the library files. Does anyone have any ideas why it's not working and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be missed boost include directory ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was confused because I had compiled the code with the same Makefile on another machine previously, so it was not clear to me why it was not working. Anyway, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, the problem was in the Makefile. More specifically, the path to the boost library was not included during the compilation of the .cpp files using boost. Fixed it by adding the library explicitly in the compilation step:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Finally, the Makefile is as follows:

```
CXX=gcc  #icpc
RM=rm -f
CPPFLAGS=-g -O3 -fopenmp
OPENMP   = -fopenmp
BIN = theVeecode_$(CXX)

LIBS= -I /path-to-boost/boost_1_53_0/
LIBS+= -L /path-to-boost/boost_1_53_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_regex

CPPSRCS=mathtools.cpp time_.cpp read_input.cpp vee_ao_calc.cpp vee_mo_calc.cpp write_int2e.cpp memory_check.cpp
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(CPPSRCS))
DEPS=Vector3.h  mathtools.h  memory_check.h  read_input.h  time_.h  vee_ao_calc.h  vee_mo_calc.h  write_int2e.h

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $< $(CPPFLAGS) $(LIBS)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) main.cpp $(OPENMP) -o $(BIN) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJS) $(BIN)

dist-clean: clean
        $(RM) $(BIN)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the word out there;

For my case, I was missing the `libboost-dev` package.

On debian, you can install it with `sudo apt install libboost-dev`